# Condition coverage vs Decision coverage testing

Tags: testing

Can I have one question? What is the difference between Condition coverage and Decision coverage?

I have simply example:

IF (A && B) THEN

Condition coverage will have two tests (The result will be false):

1. A = TRUE, B = FALSE
2. A = FALSE, B = TRUE

Decision coverage will have only one test (The result will be true):

1. A = TRUE, B = TRUE

Do I understand that right?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184807/branch-vs-decision-coverage-question

Answer (score 3):

In **Condition Coverage** (also know as Predicate Coverage) each of the boolean expressions must be evaluated to *true* and *false* at least once. For example:

IF ((A || B) && C) THEN

To satisfy the condition coverage criteria, you could use the following tests:

1) A = true  | B = not eval | C = false

2) A = false | B = true     | C = true

3) A = false | B = false    | C = not eval

In **Decision Coverage** (also know as Branch Coverage) you have to test all posible branches. For example:

...

IF (A){

ELSE IF(B){

}ELSE{

}

...

To satisfy the decision coverage criteria for this piece of code you'll need to run 3 tests:

1) A is evaluated to *true*

2) A is evaluated to *false* and B is evaluated to *true*

3) A and B are evaluated to *false*

Comment: Coverage is a number, not a testing technique. How is condition coverage measured? You described how 100% condition coverage is achieved, but what if I have 43%? How do I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

Example:

1. a = int(input())
2. if a=0:
3. ```
   print("Zero")
   ```
4. elif a>0:
5. ```
   print("Positive")
   ```
6. else:
7. ```
   print("Negative")
   ```

Here the **Statement no. 2, 4 and 6** will be considered under **Condition Coverage**. (Bcz here you are checking the condition that is it equal to 0 or not, is it greater than 0 or not, etc.)

and the **statement no. 3, 5 and 7** will be considered under **Decision coverage.**
(Bcz these are the decision taken after cheking the condition)

***Imp Note: Decision Coverage and Branch Coverage are different.***

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).